# Where to get historical 1 minute forex data?

Tags: data-request, finance

i've been searching for ways to obtain historical 1 minute forex data, does anyone knows where i can find the most realiable data?. I've found histdata.com, but i can't check how reliable it is, does anyone knows if it's reliable?

Comment: You may want to check it against http://ratedata.gaincapital.com/ which isn't per-minute but fairly close.